# How to get access token for keycloak user SPI

Tags: java, spring, keycloak

I followed this tutorial to set up a custom user SPI:

https://github.com/dasniko/keycloak-user-spi-demo/tree/master/src/main/java/dasniko/keycoak/user

I can see my users in my custom SPI from my admin console and it works fine:

Now I am trying to get an access token via postman/insomnia for the custom SPI user(s) and I get the following error:

```
"error": "invalid_grant", "error_description": "Invalid user credentials"
```

[screenshot without access token]https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y27Jt.png

My realm, client id, client secret, username, password & grant type all look fine.

I noticed that from my admin console, whenever I view a say user1 (on the admin console) then call the access token endpoint, it generates an access token (postman/insomnia).

When I view another user say user2, it generates an access token for user2 but now shows the above error for user1 when I call the endpoint again with user1 details:

[screenshot with access token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZMsqi.png)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with my external user data source.
In the tutorial, the users were hard coded in an array list.
In my implementation, I had used HttpClient to pull the users from another java SpringBoot project running locally.

My external user data store had a bug which made it return a wrong user. So authentication always failed. Except when you clicked to view the user(in the console). This I think is caches that user so when I tried to authenticate now, it gets that user data from cache